# injecting javascript during webViewDidStartLoad not working on reload

Tags: ios, ios5

I am reloading my UIWebView and for some reason the code in stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString does not seem to have an effect.  It works fine on initial view load but doesn't seem to work on reload.  Stepping through the debugger I see the webViewDidStartLoad getting called after the reload, so there must be another issue.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //pass in our default variables into the web view here
    [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var model = {taskId:'xyz', foo:'bar'};"];

}
```

and my reload method

```
- (void)refreshView{
    [mainWebView reload];   
}
```